# How to remove duplicates from a list?

Tags: java, list, collections, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates from a list but what I am doing is not working:

```
List<Customer> listCustomer = new ArrayList<Customer>();    
for (Customer customer: tmpListCustomer)
{
  if (!listCustomer.contains(customer)) 
  {
    listCustomer.add(customer);
  }
 }
```

Comment: you should not write code like this in Java, just like you should not write your own sorting routines in Java. If it has the ability to do this built in through something like Set, use that.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If the code in your question doesn't work, you probably have not implemented `equals(Object)` on the `Customer` class appropriately.

Presumably there is some key (let us call it `customerId`) that uniquely identifies a customer; e.g.

```
class Customer {
    private String customerId;
    ...
```

An appropriate definition of `equals(Object)` would look like this:

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Customer)) {
            return false;
        }
        Customer other = (Customer) obj;
        return this.customerId.equals(other.customerId);
    }
```

For completeness, you *should* also implement `hashCode` so that two `Customer` objects that are equal will return the same hash value.  A matching `hashCode` for the above definition of `equals` would be:

```
    public int hashCode() {
        return customerId.hashCode();
    }
```

It is also worth noting that this is not an efficient way to remove duplicates if the list is large.  (For a list with N customers, you will need to perform `N*(N-1)/2` comparisons in the worst case; i.e. when there are no duplicates.)  For a more efficient solution you could use a `HashSet` to do the duplicate checking.  Another option would be to use a `LinkedHashSet` as explained in Tom Hawtin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5101589/139985).

Answer (score 94):

Assuming you want to keep the current order **and don't want a `Set`**, perhaps the easiest is:

```
List<Customer> depdupeCustomers =
    new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(customers));
```

If you want to change the original list:

```
Set<Customer> depdupeCustomers = new LinkedHashSet<>(customers);
customers.clear();
customers.addAll(dedupeCustomers);
```

Comment: If you haven't overridden the object's (Customer's) equals method, the HashSet will compare the objects' location in memory so they will not be equal and you will still have duplicates in your new Set.

Comment: @GinjaNinja There is an implicit assumption that `equals` (and `hashCode`) is implemented in a way which makes sense for the type. For instance a, `LinkedHashSet<JWindow>` would only remove duplicates that were exactly the same object because that's what it means for `JWindow` instances to be equal.

Answer (score 30):

**java 8 update**
you can use stream of array as below:

```
Arrays.stream(yourArray).distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Best solution. With a set you lose the order (which may be a requirement or not, but with this solution you don't have to think about it).

Comment: You could also use TreeSet but then you have to implement Comparable, which is not always desirable

Comment: How would I get around the "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<String>" error from this?

Comment: I think you can use map method in your chain about `Type Casting`

Comment: Java 8 Lambdas are just kickass and exactly what we all demanded, having to work daily with java. Made our lifes much easier!

Comment: This just adds the results to a `Set` behind the scenes and then checks if the set contains the value before passing it downstream. This is functionally equivalent to OP's solution and [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5101589/1941654) but likely to be less efficient, depending on the implementation. That being said, if it's easier to read for the team then it's a good option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506426/remove-old-object-after-comparing-userid-and-date-from-list-android

Can anyone help here ?

Comment: @cocorossello - *"With a set you lose the order ..."* -  It depends on 1) the kind of set you are talking about and 2) how you *use* the set!!

Comment: TreeSet is a SortedSet, besides, I do mention that if you use a plain Set you lose the order, but it may not be a requirement, this is not mentioned at all

Answer (score 13):

## List → Set → List (distinct)

Just add all your elements to a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html): it does not allow it's elements to be repeated. If you need a list afterwards, use new `ArrayList(theSet)` constructor afterwards (where `theSet` is your resulting set).

Comment: Using a Set would produce exactly the same results as the code written above, just faster. The poster says "doesn't work" not "works too slowly".

Comment: well Set works and his code doesn't so which is better working code that is correct and you don't have to write, or buggy code that you don't really understand and doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are assuming that he only wants to remove duplicate references to the same object. If that were the case, then the posted code would work.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop: Set does exactly what his code does.  It's almost certainly the equals(Object) and hashCode() methods that are the problem here; the difference between object equality and value equality.

Answer (score 13):

Does Customer implement the `equals()` contract?

If it doesn't implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, then `listCustomer.contains(customer)` will check to see if the exact same *instance* already exists in the list (By instance I mean the exact same object--memory address, etc). If what you are looking for is to test whether or not the same *Customer*( perhaps it's the same customer if they have the same customer name, or customer number) is in the list already, then you would need to override `equals()` to ensure that it checks whether or not the relevant fields(e.g. customer names) match.

Note: Don't forget to override `hashCode()` if you are going to override `equals()`! Otherwise, you might get trouble with your HashMaps and other data structures. For a good coverage of why this is and what pitfalls to avoid, consider having a look at Josh Bloch's [Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PP1&ots=yXJjJeq4R1&dq=josh%20bloch%20equals&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q&f=false) chapters on `equals()` and `hashCode()` (The link only contains iformation about why you must implement `hashCode()` when you implement `equals()`, but there is good coverage about how to override `equals()` too).

By the way, is there an ordering restriction on your set? If there isn't, a slightly easier way to solve this problem is use a `Set<Customer>` like so:

```
Set<Customer> noDups = new HashSet<Customer>();
noDups.addAll(tmpListCustomer);
return new ArrayList<Customer>(noDups);
```

Which will nicely remove duplicates for you, since Sets don't allow duplicates. However, this will lose any ordering that was applied to `tmpListCustomer`, since `HashSet` has no explicit ordering (You can get around that by using a `TreeSet`, but that's not exactly related to your question). This can simplify your code a little bit.

Comment: +1 for remembering that Set can't be used if you need to maintain order.

Comment: for the suggestion of `TreeSet<>()` to maintain order: +1

Answer (score 9):

I suspect you might not have `Customer.equals()` implemented properly (or at all).

`List.contains()` uses `equals()` to verify whether any of its elements is identical to the object passed as parameter. However, the default implementation of `equals` tests for physical identity, not value identity. So if you have not overwritten it in `Customer`, it will return false for two distinct Customer objects having identical state.

Here are the nitty-gritty details of [how to implement `equals`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) (and [`hashCode`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28), which is its pair - you must practically always implement both if you need to implement either of them). Since you haven't shown us the Customer class, it is difficult to give more concrete advice.

As others have noted, you are better off using a Set rather than doing the job by hand, but even for that, you still need to implement those methods.

Comment: Override equals and hashCode methods from java.lang.Object.  You'll want to read this: http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf

Comment: the correct way to remove duplicates from a list in Java is to use a Set. And you can't just override equals() without overriding hashCode() as well.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop: A Set is not magic, and can't detect that two Customers are equal when you haven't written the code to tell them. Using Set will have exactly the same results as the posted code, just faster.

Comment: @fuzzy, of course, I was just adding the relevant explanation while you were writing your comment. Why are you riding this single technical detail, which - although of course important _in the long run_ - has nothing to do directly with solving the concrete question?

Answer (score 6):

```
private void removeTheDuplicates(List<Customer>myList) {
    for(ListIterator<Customer>iterator = myList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Customer customer = iterator.next();
        if(Collections.frequency(myList, customer) > 1) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myList.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The "contains" method searched for whether the list contains an entry that returns true from Customer.equals(Object o). If you have not overridden equals(Object) in Customer or one of its parents then it will only search for an existing occurrence of the same object. It may be this was what you wanted, in which case your code should work. But if you were looking for not having two objects both representing the same customer, then you need to override equals(Object) to return true when that is the case.

It is also true that using one of the implementations of Set instead of List would give you duplicate removal automatically, and faster (for anything other than very small Lists). You will still need to provide code for equals.

You should also override hashCode() when you override equals().

Comment: I did not downvote it, but I think your suggestion to override `equals` to delete duplicates might have earned it.

Comment: You mean the suggestion that is the same as the accepted answer?

Comment: @DJClayworth: After reading your post more carefully I do agree that it's totally correct ( On my first reading I though you suggested to do a `special case` equals ). You get my +1 for unfair downvoting.  On the other hand, looking at other posts here, somebody had been on the downvoting vengeance spree.

Answer (score 4):

Nearly all of the above answers are right but what I suggest is to use a Map or Set while creating the related list, not after to gain performance. Because converting a list to a Set or Map and then reconverting it to a List again is a trivial work.

Sample Code:

```
Set<String> stringsSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();//A Linked hash set 
//prevents the adding order of the elements
for (String string: stringsList) {
    stringsSet.add(string);
}
return new ArrayList<String>(stringsSet);
```

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions:

- Use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList. This will speed up the contains() checks considerably if you have a long list
- Make sure Customer.equals() and Customer.hashCode() are implemented properly, i.e. they should be based on the combined values of the underlying fields in the customer object.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you are probably not implementing equals() correctly.

However, you should also note that this code is considered quite inefficient, since the runtime could be the number of elements squared.

You might want to consider using a Set structure instead of a List instead, or building a Set first and then turning it into a list.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is:

```
List<XXX> lstConsultada = dao.findByPropertyList(YYY);
List<XXX> lstFinal = new ArrayList<XXX>(new LinkedHashSet<GrupoOrigen>(XXX));
```

and override `hascode` and `equals` over the Id's properties of each entity

Answer (score 1):

IMHO best way how to do it these days:

Suppose you have a Collection "**dups**" and you want to create another Collection containing the same elements but with all duplicates eliminated. The following one-liner does the trick.

```
Collection<collectionType> noDups = new HashSet<collectionType>(dups);
```

It works by creating a Set which, by definition, cannot contain duplicates.

*Based on oracle doc.*

Comment: To add to this answer, using a `Set` wastes a bunch of space too, something that can potentially be avoided here.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer for Java is use a [Set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). If you already have a `List<Customer>` and want to de duplicate it

```
Set<Customer> s = new HashSet<Customer>(listCustomer);
```

Otherise just use a `Set` implemenation `HashSet`, `TreeSet` directly and skip the `List` construction phase.

You will need to override [`hashCode()` and `equals()`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html) on your domain classes that are put in the `Set` as well to make sure that the behavior you want actually what you get. `equals()` can be as simple as comparing unique ids of the objects to as complex as comparing every field. `hashCode()` can be as simple as returning the `hashCode()` of the unique id' `String` representation or the `hashCode()`.

Comment: speed isn't as important as maintainability, you don't have to maintain the code for Set and it is self documenting and the correct Java idiom.

Comment: Homer:You can do it the right way, the wrong way, or the Max Power way. Bart:What's the Max Power way? Homer: It's the wrong way, only faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using java 8 stream api.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("one");
    list.add("one");
    list.add("two");
    System.out.println(list);
    Collection<String> c = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println(c);
```

Output:

Before values : [one, one, two]

After Values : [one, two]

Comment: This is not quite what the original author, asked about. You are making a set not a list