# Method to remove duplicates in List

Tags: java, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicates from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

Is there any method in Java List that I can use to remove duplicates?

Comment: Isn't this answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/remove-duplicates-from-a-list

Comment: Maybe you should use a Set instead of a List in the first place.

Comment: I really like the irony that a question about removing duplicates has been removed... because it's a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no method on `java.lang.List` that removes duplicates. It seems that the designers expected that `List` would not be used in scenarios where you are worried about duplicates:

> Unlike sets, lists typically allow duplicate elements. More formally, lists typically allow pairs of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and they typically allow multiple null elements if they allow null elements at all. It is not inconceivable that someone might wish to implement a list that prohibits duplicates, by throwing runtime exceptions when the user attempts to insert them, but we expect this usage to be rare.
>
> (taken from [java.lang.List Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html))

You will either need to use a `Set` or implement your own method for removing duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, there isn't. The `List` interface suppors models of standard list structures and a standard list doesn't care about duplicates. Therefore: `List` doesn't have an abstract `removeDuplicate()` or something.

You could implement your own list, that doesn't allow duplicates being added. The backing list would be an arraylist:

```
public class SetList<T> implements List<T> {
  private List<T> internal = new ArrayList<T>();

  // some constructors

  // all adding methods and contructors do a check first
  // example:

  public SetList<T>(Collection<T> others) {
    for (T other:others)
      add(other);  // adds all items except duplicates
  }

  @Override
  public void add(T item) {
    if (!internal.contains(item))
      return internal.add(item);
    else
      return false;
  }

  // other methods simply delegate to the internal list
  // examples:
  @Override 
  public void clear() {internal.clear();}

  @Override
  public Iteratory<T> iterator() {return internal.iterator();}
}
```

Addition - you could even add the `Set` interface, than you have a set implementation that keeps insertion order.

---

Note - with the same technique you could implement a custom `List` - again backed by a real `ArrayList`, that offers an additional method to remove duplicates (from the backing list)

Comment: is there any predefined method to remove duplicates in lists

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the elements is important, you might want to consider instantiating a LinkedHashSet, passing your list to its constructor.  The iterator that you can then call on this LinkedHashSet will give you all of your list items, in the original order, but with the duplicates removed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method to remove duplicates from a `List`.

Your options are:

- Use a Set instead of a List ... provided that you don't care about the order of the elements in your original list.
- Use the approach of a List that doesn't allow duplicates to be inserted as described by @Andreas_D.
- Rebuild the list as per the following code:

  ```
  List list = new ArrayList();    
  for (Object obj: inputList) {
      if (!list.contains(obj)) {
          list.add(obj);
      }
  }
  ```

  This is `O(N^2)` because `list.contains(obj)` is `O(N)`.
- Rebuild the list as per the following code:

  ```
  List list = new ArrayList();
  HashSet seen = new HashSet();
  for (Object obj: inputList) {
      if (!seen.add(obj)) {
          list.add(obj);
      }
  }
  ```

  This is `O(N)` if you make certain assumptions about the behaviour of the hash function.

And there are other variations.

Caveat, all solutions based on `Collection` classes require that certain methods are implemented correctly / consistently by your element class.  But that's a given for any classes that follows Java *best practice*.