# Remove duplicate beans from a list

Tags: java

I am looping through a set of beans and doing a check for something and adding to a list.  I only want to add one occurrence of a particular item

```
List<PartsBean> beans = hotPartsDAO.getDeletedList(user);
List<FinalItemBean> finalItemList = new ArrayList<FinalItemBean>();
for (PartsBean bean : beans)
{
    if (!bean.getFinalItem().isActive())
    {
        finalItemList.add(bean.getFinalItem());
    }
}
```

In the list I get for example

```
"test"
"test"
"test"
"hello"
```

I just want 1 "test"

If I were to use a set then how would I modify this so that I can add the components of that set to this below:

This here is how its currently being passed over `List<FinalItemBean> list`

```
protected final void buildFinalItemFilterList( Action action, PartsDAO dao, List<FinalItemBean> list )

    throws SQLException
{
    List<FinalItemBean> finalItems = dao.getAllFinalItems( false );
    FinalItemBean finalItem;

    for (FinalItemBean e: list )
    {
         finalItem = dao.getFinalItemById(e.getId());
         finalItems.add(finalItem);
    }

    Collections.sort( finalItems );
    action.setRequestAttribute("finalItems", finalItems );
}
```

Comment: Use a `Set` instead of a `List`, job done :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface list has a Method called contains, which return a true if that 'occurrence' is on the list and a false if is not in the list.
Like:

```
if(!myList.contains(person)) myList.add(person);
```

Pretty easy. You could also use a Set instead, but, I think lists are more flexible than sets, or that's what some developers believe.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm this seems like I can keep my list

Comment: Use this as a condition before adding it to the list, or as other fellows said use a set.

Comment: Im about to try what you have....that way i want have to modify any code anywhere else.....the set seems straightforward either way

Comment: Developers should not use the most *flexible* interface but the most *accurate* interface. If you don't have to access items by index, then why to use a list?

Comment: so yogu...I should be using a set instead of a list?

Comment: As I've written in my answer, yes. If you were required to call the `get` method, you would have to use a list, but that is not the case as I see.

Comment: @Yogu mmm... That's the other reason why I prefer lists over sets, the indexes. You'll never know when you'll need it when you manage data structures.

Comment: If you use lists without need, you can't assign collections to your variables. For local variables that's no big deal, but it is annoying to have `List` parameter that actually could be a `Collection` if you want to pass a collection.

Comment: But why is annoying?...That's just what I do. I think this is a kind of paradigm discussion, I see you're more Java-pure-style and I am a developer who want to solve problems, no matter if is or not the pure style.

Comment: Im mos def not a java pure guy......but Im open to all things....using contains solved it without me having to modify code all over the place....had I Forseen dup's when i was first coding this I most likely would have used a SET....thanks

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest to use a `Set` of `FinalItemBean` instead of a list. If you have many beans, this will even improve performance, because the common `HashSet` implementation is very fast at checking whether items already exist.

Comment: @Doc: Using `Set` is a good idea. Note that you will also have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in `EndItemBean` and it's derivatives to _help_ `Set` identify duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashSet instead of a List.

You can create your List with code like this:

```
Set s = new HashSet();
//add here
List l = new ArrayList();
l.addAll(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Set` because sets don't allow duplicates where as
and `List` allows duplicates.