# I have to remove duplicates from list (special condition)

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, duplicates, equals

I have a Class ArrayList so I have to **delete duplicates Keywords** when their Autor are same, but **not when theses are different**. The follow code remove duplicates OK only in the first Index (i=0), then it doesn't remove anything.

Thanks you!

Example:

Here I have an example :

1   A   PPP

2   A   EEE

3   B   AAA

4   B   LL

5   A   CCC

**2 A   EEE**

**5 A   CCC**

In this cases I don't want to remove anyline because "A" has a different parent (2 and 5).

```
        int size = ls.size();
    int duplicates = 0;

    // not using a method in the check also speeds up the execution
    // also i must be less that size-1 so that j doesn't
    // throw IndexOutOfBoundsException
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {

                    if(ls.get(j).getKeywords().equals(ls.get(i).getKeywords()) && ls.get(j).getAutor().equals(ls.get(i).getAutor()) ){
                        duplicates++;
                        ls.remove(j);}


            // decrease j because the array got re-indexed
            j--;
            // decrease the size of the array
            size--;
        } // for j
    } // fo
```

Comment: What type is the content of ls? Please consider reducing/extending your code to make it http://sscce.org/

Comment: I observe that I am having a problem with the size.

Comment: The content is of the registers in list are Strings

Comment: What's `rama`? Why are you creating all those Strings but ever using them? Why are you incrementing `duplicates` when none was found (use curly braces with all `if`s!)? Why are you decreasing `j` and `size` even when nothing is removed?

Comment: @user1741407 The contents are *not* Strings. Strings don't have methods named `.getAutor()` or `.getKeywords()`

Comment: Yes, I'am sorry. I modified de code.

Comment: Properly implement equals on the contents of the list 'ls' and then simply use a Set implementation instead of a List.

Comment: If you have `List` datra structure and want to remove duplicates, try to use data structure that cannot contain duplicates, I mean `Set` .

Comment: @NullUserException: Yes, unless you choose a special implementation like TreeSet, which orders elements by their natural order (Comparable).

Comment: @NullUserException Really, What about LinkedHashSet or TreeSet?

Comment: Could you put a bit more details in the example and add more context to the code, it should at least be compileable.

Comment: Ok, excuse me. I am going to write a complete example. Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A best approch for this problem is create list of `non duplicates`. So declare another list and while iterating on first list check whether item is present in that list if not then only add that item. Below is the sample source code.

Note that I have deliberately used loop and equals to simulate your conditions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //Add some duplicates
        list.add(new Integer(4));
        list.add(new Integer(5));
        list.add(new Integer(6));
    }
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer first : list) {
        boolean contains = false;//if this flag is false after iteration then item will be added

        for (Integer copy : newList)
            if (first.equals(copy)) {// You will have to specify your condition here
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        if(!contains)
            newList.add(first);//add item if it was not present
    }
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(newList);

}
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6] <-- List with duplicates
[4, 5, 6] <-- List with no duplicates
```

Comment: This won't work if you don't know what elements will be there in the list. It will only work if the list will always hold the same values.

Comment: @bot  I don't know where the question of not working come from. It will always work. Iterations are such that it only depends on equals method if you add something else condition there it will work on that condition.

Comment: You don't understand what I am saying. Your approach requires that you create a list containing the possible items that can appear in another list. This means that you need to know the items that will appear in the second list before hand. What do you do when you don't know what items will appear in the list? I could add a and b today and c and d tomorrow. Your program will require the user to provide a list containing no duplicates. You use this list to remove duplicates from another list. If the user has to input a list with no duplicates, then what's the program for?

Comment: I am sorry. I guess you are right. I jumped to a conclusion before seeing your code. My bad

Comment: Items that will appear in second list  will depend on the condition to for elements to exist. Like in op case he can simply change equals with his condition and he will get the list based on that condition

Answer (score 0):

You can group you list by key and postprocess to remove dublicates:

[Implementing GroupBy using Google guava Multimap and Function](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=228)

**EDIT:**

Another interesting way is to implement equals method and using hashset (or like), see:

[Remove duplicates from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849498/926620)

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've used another solution, but I read these and are good alts.