# Java How To Keep Unique Values In A List of Objects

Tags: java, list, dictionary, unique

I currently am retrieving a list of objects `List<NprDto>` (The NprDto class contains accountId, theDate1, and theDate2) from a query that returns results where the NprDto has duplicate accountIds. I need to have a `List<NproDto>` of only unique accountIds but keep the object. It only needs to add the first accountId it comes across and ignores the rest.

I'm currently trying this:

```
private List<NprDto> getUniqueAccountList(List<NprDto> nonUniqueAccountList) throws Exception {

    Map<Long,NprDto> uniqueAccountsMapList = new HashMap<Long,NprDto>();
    List<NprDto> uniqueAccountsList = null;

    if(nonUniqueAccountList != null && !nonUniqueAccountList.isEmpty()) {
        for(NprDto nprDto : nonUniqueAccountList) {
            uniqueAccountsMapList.put(Long.valueOf(nprDto.getAccountId()), nprDto);
        }
    }

    uniqueAccountsList = new ArrayList<NprDto>(uniqueAccountsMapList.values());

    return uniqueAccountsList;

}
```

But this doesn't seem to be  working because when I iterate through the returned uniqueAccountsList later it only picks up the first object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have unique account numbers?  I think your design is good (saves a lot of the work you need to do a Set), and your code looks good too.  I'm betting your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I had an output statement in the wrong location. Everything is working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I need to have a List of only unique accountIds but keep the
>   object.

You should use `Set<NprDto>`. For that you need to override `equals` and `hasCode` at `NproDto` class.

```
class NprDto{
   Long accountId;
   .......

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   NproDto other=(NproDto) obj;
   return this.accountId==other.accountId;
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    return accountId.hashCode();
 }
}
```

---

Change your `getUniqueAccountList` as follows:

```
private Set<NprDto> getUniqueAccountSet(){    
  Map<Long,NprDto> uniqueAccountsMapList = new HashMap<Long,NprDto>();
  Set<NprDto> uniqueAccs = new HashSet<NprDto>(uniqueAccountsMapList.values());    
  return uniqueAccs;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you need here is a `LinkedHashSet`. It removes duplicates and keeps insertion order.
You **do not** need `TreeSet` here because it sorts and changes the order of the original `List`.

If preserving insertion order is not important use a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to implements equals and hascode method, it will be good for you

[Remove duplicates from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

Java Set contains the Unique value but its unsorted collection. List is sorted collection but contains the duplicates objects.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is implement the `equals`, `hashCode` and `compareTo` methods for `NprDto` to match two objects as equal when their ID is the same. Then you can filter all duplicates as easy as this:

```
private List<NprDto> getUniqueAccountList(List<NprDto> nonUniqueAccountList) {
    return new ArrayList<NprDto>(new LinkedHashSet<NprDto>(nonUniqueAccountList));
}
```