# Remove duplicates from ArrayList when objects have not same reference

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a problem at the moment on my project. I have 1 arraylist (Lets call it BIG) that is formed by another 3 arraylists (A,B,C) from a SQL query each, so I have basically duplicated items (sometimes even same Item 3 or more times) in the BIG arraylist.

My problem is that I cannot use the .contains() method since the references of the objects are different between them (even though some objects represent the same "item"), and as "primary key", the attribute that never changes inside each item in arraylist is the ID of the items (an int). How can I do to delete duplicated elemets so I can get with only one of each "items"?

Comment: The contains() method does not compare references, it uses .equals() on the objects contained in the list. You need to implement equals() and hashcode() on that class, as suggested by @Java Learner

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `Equals` method of that class, as per the business requirement.

And ofcourse `hashcode` method, because if **equals** is overridden **hashcode** method also should be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Explained well here :

[How to remove duplicates from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

In `equals` check id attributes of both objects.