# How to remove duplicates from list<object>

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, arraylist

I have a object in java called foo.
I can do `foo.getDate();` and that will give me the date of one item.
But now I have a `list<foo>` and I want to get per item one date.
So if I loop through my list I will see this output:

```
3-1-2015
3-1-2015
5-1-2015
8-1-2015
8-1-2015
```

But I want to see:

```
3-1-2015
5-1-2015
8-1-2015
```

So I want that only the first item with a unique date will be added to the list.
How can I do this in Java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?  There are lots of ways to do this such as extending `ArrayList` and overriding the add method with some logic to check if that item already exists.  Another way might be to add some logic before the add method to check if it exists already and decide to add or not.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a set, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Set which will store unique Dates. If date from your foo instance was not already added to set add this instance to list containing foo objects with unique dates.

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
//fill list with your foo instances


Set<Date> uniqueDates = new HashSet<>();
List<Foo> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Foo f : list){
    if (uniqueDates.add(f.getDate())){//if I was able to add date to set
        //it means that instance with this date is seen first time
        //so I can add it to result list
        resultList.add(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most easy way would be use a map (`HashMap` for example)... Use the Date as a key, then put all your Foo objects into it. Then every time a key already exists the value will be overwritten and you'll end up with only one Foo object per Date. If you need a list (for sorting, for example) you can do something like `new ArrayList<Foo>( myMap.values() );` then.

Answer (score 0):

well you probably should use `Set` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Pshemo's answer, doing the same with Java 8 is straightforward:

```
public class RemoveDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Initialize some dates
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date d1 = new Date(now);
        Date d2 = new Date(now - 10_000_000_000L);
        Date d3 = new Date(now - 100_000_000_000L);

        // Initialize some Foos with the dates    
        List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Foo(d3), new Foo(d3), new Foo(d2), 
            new Foo(d1), new Foo(d1)));

        Set<Date> uniqueDates = new HashSet<>();

        // Filter foos whose date is already in the set    
        List<Foo> distinct = list.stream().filter(
            f -> uniqueDates.add(f.getDate())).
            collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(distinct); // [Foo [date=17/01/12], 
                                      //  Foo [date=24/11/14], 
                                      //  Foo [date=19/03/15]]

    }

    static class Foo {

        private static DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

        private final Date date;

        Date getDate() {
            return this.date;
        }

        Foo(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [date=" + formatter.format(this.date) + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

The principle is exactly the same: if the date is already in the set, then the `Foo` is filtered from the stream.