# Removing duplicates in a Spinner in java when data comes from mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, android-spinner, hashset

I am Using hashsetList to create a new list for my spinner without duplicates but java gives errors when I add this within the Spinner. Ithe project works fine when duplicates are shown from mySQL.

Here is the extract of MainActivity.java before I created the hashsetList.

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate spinner1 in activity_main.xml
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        // Spinner adapter

        spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,typesofjobs));

       Collections.sort(typesofjobs);
```

When I added the following hashsetList code to eliminate duplicates and run it, the project crashes.

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate spinner1 in activity_main.xml
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


        Set<String> hashsetList = new HashSet<String>(typesofjobs);
        // Spinner adapter

        spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, (List<String>) hashsetList));

        Collections.sort(typesofjobs);
```

Am I putting hashsetList in the wrong place or using it incorrectly? I am just trying to replace "typesofjobs" with the non duplicate version. Is there a better way I could eliminate my spinner duplicates?

Comment: What is your error output and do you know the exact line where your program is crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track when you used `HashSet` with your list to remove the duplicates.  However, you made a mistake when you tried to cast this `Set` to a `List`, which won't work.  Instead, in the code below I pass a `LinkedHashSet` created from your list of jobs into an `ArrayList` constructor.  The resulting `List` will have all duplicate `String` job values removed.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
    // Locate spinner1 in activity_main.xml
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    List<String> typesofjobsunique = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(typesofjobs));
    spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, typesofjobsunique));

    // not sure if you want to keep original list
    Collections.sort(typesofjobs);
```

Hat tip to [this great SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list) which discusses ways to remove duplicates from Java `List`s.