# The List having duplicate data when I using left outer join in query

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

This is how I display my listView, but when I display using this kind of method it gives me duplicate data. I think this is because my "CondimentDescription" will have more than 1 data. The following is my code:

```
public List<OrderList> getOrderList() {
            List<OrderList> OrderList = new ArrayList<OrderList>();
            OrderList list = new OrderList();
            try {
                String selectQuery = "select t2.Id,t2.ProductCode,t2.Price,t2.Qty,t3.Description,t4.condimentDescription from TempCS t1 \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSDetail t2 on t1.DocNo=t2.Docno\n" +
                        "left outer join mProduct t3 on t2.ProductCode=t3.Code \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSCondiment t4 on t2.SeqNo=t4.SeqNo"+
                        "where t1.DocNo=" + TablePageDocNo + "\n";

                SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        list.setProductCode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProductCode")));
                        list.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Price"))));
                        list.setQty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Qty")));
                        list.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Description")));
                        list.set_ID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"))));
         //this will more than 1 row in my Sqlite database  
                        list.setCondimentDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CondimentDescription")));
                                OrderList.add(list);
                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }

            }catch(Exception e){
            }

        return OrderList;
    }
```

Adapter List

```
public class  OrderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        public OrderListAdapter() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ListFragmentActivity.this);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return orderlist.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listproduct1, null);
            }

            final TextView _ID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proID);
            _ID.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).get_ID());
            final String proID = _ID.getText().toString();

            final TextView ProductCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productcode);
            ProductCode.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).getProductCode());

            final TextView Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            Description.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).getDescription());

            final TextView Price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        Price.setText("" + String.format("%.2f",orderlist.get(position).getPrice()));
        final Double price= Double.valueOf(Price.getText().toString());

        final TextView Qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        Qty.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).getQty());

        final TextView condimentDescription=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.condimentDescription);
        condimentDescription.setText("" + orderlist.get(position).getCondimentDescription());

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38323180/6799753)

Comment: @VishrutPatil This link is work but not what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicates from a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

quickly look at your code :

```
"left outer join TempCSCondiment t4 on t2.SeqNo=t2.SeqNo"+
```

It might goes wrong here. you want to join t4, but the on clause :

> t2.SeqNo=t2.SeqNo"

And I suppose that your data is not duplicated ( and you know the result of different kind of join type).

Comment: this is my mistake but not the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should give same column name in getColumnIndex() method as in Database.

Try this:

```
public List<OrderList> getOrderList() {


            SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getReadableDatabase();

            String selectQuery = "select t2.Id,t2.ProductCode,t2.Price,t2.Qty,t3.Description,t4.condimentDescription from TempCS t1 \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSDetail t2 on t1.DocNo=t2.Docno\n" +
                        "left outer join mProduct t3 on t2.ProductCode=t3.Code \n" +
                        "left outer join TempCSCondiment t4 on t2.SeqNo=t2.SeqNo"+
                        "where t1.DocNo=" + TablePageDocNo + "\n";

            Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            List<OrderList> OrderList = new ArrayList<OrderList>();
            OrderList list = new OrderList();
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        list.setProductCode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProductCode")));
                        list.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Price"))));
                        list.setQty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Qty")));
                        list.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Description")));
                        list.set_ID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id"))));
         //this will more than 1 row in my Sqlite database  
                        list.setCondimentDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("condimentDescription")));
                                OrderList.add(list);
                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }

            }catch(Exception e){
            }

        return OrderList;
    }
```