# How to remove repeated element from list?

Tags: java, list, jpa, collections

I have two lists `results` and `dateObj`. In `dateObj` list I added the months between two dates, and the other list contains list of months, so I should remove the repeated months from `dateObj` list.

This is my attempt :

```
public void nbreRep(ActionEvent e) {
    List<Object[]> results;
    List<String> dateObj = new ArrayList<String>();
    Date date_de;
    Date date_a;
    Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginCalendar.setTime(date_de);
    finishCalendar.setTime(date_a);
    while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {
        Date datediff = beginCalendar.getTime();
        beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        fC = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar fCa = Calendar.getInstance();
        fC.setTime(datediff);
        fCa.setTime(datediff);
        int year = fCa.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String d = fC.getDisplayName(fC.MONTH, fC.LONG, Locale.FRANCE) + " " + year;
        Object[] obj = new Object[2];
        obj[0] = d;
        obj[1] = 1;
        dateObj.add(obj);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dateObj.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("index " + i + "value " + dateObj.get(i));
    }
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select r.dateheurerep, count(r) as nbrr "
                    + "  from Reparation r "
                    + " where r.dateheurerep >= :date_de "
                    + "   and r.dateheurerep <= :date_a "
                    + " GROUP BY YEAR(r.dateheurerep), MONTH(r.dateheurerep)");
    query.setParameter("date_de", date_de);
    query.setParameter("date_a", date_a);
    results = query.getResultList();
    results.addAll(dateObj);
}
```

Comment: Something is not right about your code: it's impossible to put a two-element object array in a `List<String>`. Please post real code, and also try to explain what this code is supposed to do. And to print the contents of an array, use `Arrays.toString(...)` - you can't use the name of the array as arrays don't have a `toString` method.

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes.  You should use the appropriate class in the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: You should rarely encounter a need to type the word "Object" in your code.  If you do, stop and question whether you're doing something wrong with an otherwise strongly typed language.

Comment: Also, you're asking two questions here.  It is not good form to ask multiple unrelated questions in the same question.  Please break this up into two different questions if you need answers to both.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it's impossible to put a two-element object array in a List<String>, what should I do ?

Comment: On support of @JoeC’s comment, when you need to handle calendar months, [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) is ideal for that.

Comment: I just read your question again, and the more I try to understand what you want, the more confused I get. From which of the two lists do you want to remove elements? Also asking because in your code you are only adding elements, I see no attempt at removal. Do you want to remove elements that come twice in the list? Elements that are also in the other list? Elements that are *not* in the other list?

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, I want to remove the repeated element from `dateObj` because the other list can contains the same months

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicates from a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to get rid of duplicates is to use some helper Object and a Set.

Lets call the helper object `ObjectContainer` 
It could very simple just two fields `string` and `intValue`

In order to use it in a `Set` we have to implement `hashCode` and `equals`.
To easily show it's content we implement the `toString` method.

And to make it convertible into an `Object[]`it has a `toObjectArray` method.

```
final class ObjectContainer {
    public String string;
    public int intValue;

    public ObjectContainer(String string, int intValue) {
        this.string = string;
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
        ObjectContainer other= (ObjectContainer)obj;
        if (string == null) return other.string == null; 
        return other.intValue == intValue && string.equals(other.string);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "ObjectContainer[" + string + "," + intValue + "]";
    }

    public Object[] toObjectArray() {
        return new Object[]{string, intValue};
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 3 * intValue + 7 * (string != null ? string.hashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

For being able to add all the elements of our `ObjectContainer` Collection to a List of `Object[]` we implement some helper

```
public static List<Object[]>addAll(List<Object[]> list, Collection<ObjectContainer> c) {
    List<Object[]> result = list;
    if (list == null ) {
        result = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    for (ObjectContainer cont : c) {
        result.add(cont.toObjectArray());
    }
    return result;
}
```

When we want to use it we do something like:

```
    HashSet<ObjectContainer> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(new ObjectContainer("test", 1));
```

The `HashSet`ensures that each element occurs only once.

To add the elements to the list of results we write:

```
    List<Object[]> results = new ArrayList<>();

    addAll(results, set);
```

Maybe it's better to add the list of results to the `Set` but this is left to you.