# Remove duplicates elements from ArrayList which compose of Collection

Tags: java, list, collections

How I can remove duplicates of ArrayList?

If collection type is Car,

```
public class Car{

String Name;
String Color;
String Door;
...
}
```

ArrayList carList = new ArrayList;

Remove duplicate of carList, but it removes if which elements same Name, Color, Door.

I want remove duplicate of arraylist by specific component. like Name.

If you know about this, Please help me.

Comment: Actually, this link may be even more useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list

Comment: @TimBiegelseisen not really duplcate because he want to remove "duplicate" which are not complete duplicates, bu only duplicate of name

Comment: How have you tried to compare the elements? car.equals(anotherCar) won´t work here as it would have to be a copy from the object

Comment: @azro Duplicate of the second link, sorry.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim Yes I think of it. compare each other until arraylist's length but it is not good. If arraylist comes big, it spend a lot of time to duplicate arraylist

Comment: What I mean is you should set up a method that does the comparison between two car objects for you, where you do something like that if(car.name.equals(othercar.name) && car.color.equals(othercar.color) ...