# Remove Old Object After comparing userid and date from List Android?

Tags: android, list, sorting, arraylist

I have data something like this in my array list.

I have tried this code.

```
Collections.sort(streamList, new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                Stream p1 = (Stream) o1;
                Stream p2 = (Stream) o2;
                return p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
            }
        });

List<Stream> streamList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Before Remove Old Date Duplicate Values with the same userId:

```
[
  {
    "userName": "25",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:54 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "26",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:55 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "27",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:55 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "27",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:56 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "28",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:55 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "28",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:55 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "29",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:57 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "30",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:58 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "30",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:39:50 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "27",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:39:56 GMT+05:30 2020"
  }
]
```

Expected Output After Remove Old Date Duplicate Values with the same userId :

```
[
  {
    "userName": "25",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:54 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "26",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:55 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "28",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:55 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "29",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:38:57 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "30",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:39:50 GMT+05:30 2020"
  },
  {
    "userName": "27",
    "Date": "Thu Aug 20 18:39:56 GMT+05:30 2020"
  }
]
```

Stream.java

```
 public class Stream {
 
   /** Property userName */
   String userName;
 
   /** Property date */
   Date date;
 
   /**
    * Constructor
    */
   public Stream() {
   }
 
   /**
    * Gets the userName
    */
   public String getUserName() {
      return this.userName;
   }
 
   /**
    * Sets the userName
    */
   public void setUserName(String value) {
      this.userName = value;
   }
 
   /**
    * Gets the Date
    */
   public Date getDate() {
      return this.date;
   }
 
   /**
    * Sets the Date
    */
   public void setDate(Date value) {
      this.date = value;
   }
}
```